# Can I use ReSharper to enforce commenting standards?

Tags: c#, resharper

Been playing a lot recently with ReSharper and one thing I'd love to setup for my team are notifications if a C# class or C# file doesn't have a set code commenting standard. Unfortunately I have not yet been able to find much on the topic.

For example, I'd like to ensure all methods or functions have a comment description above them:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of MyMethod here.
/// </summary>
public void MyMethod();
```

I would like to also see that a basic check for whether (Number of lines of code) / (Number of lines of comments) is around some magic happy-medium, and create a notification or warning if not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One simple option to start with (which doesn't even need R#) is to turn on the generation of an XML documentation file, and then treat warnings as errors. That will ensure that *every* public member has documentation.

It won't ensure that the comments are *good*, of course... but it will ensure they exist.

EDIT: R# *does* have a setting for this - under Code Inspection, Inspection Severity, C#, Compiler Warnings, look for `CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member` (and related warnings near it). Change the severity of that to Error and it *might* help you - but it's hard to say as you're in an unusual environment.

Comment: Very neat solution to the first part of the question under normal circumstances - However I specifically require an R# solution as we are using the Unity3D Engine which does not use Visual Studio to perform the build of the project, and I therefore cannot make good use of the above.

Comment: @S.Richmond: I'm confused - R# is a Visual Studio plugin. If you're not using VS, how are you going to use R#? Also, every C# compiler I've ever seen is able to produce XML documentation output - have you looked for that option? It's not specific to Visual Studio. For example, using mcs (the Mono C# compiler) you use the `-doc` argument. Finally, if you've got odd requirements, you should include them in the question to start with.

Comment: No we are using VS2012, however Unity3D only makes use of it as an IDE. Unity3D performs the build itself. My question specifically asked for an R# solution for that reason.

Comment: @S.Richmond: Well if you're not doing a build in VS at all, the most I'd expect R# to be able to do is add squiggles and maybe show errors while a file is open. But again, I would expect you to be able to generate documentation as part of *whatever* is doing the build. (What happens when you hit Build in Visual Studio? Does that automatically kick off a Unity3D build without touching the MS compiler at all? All of this should have been explained in the question...)

Comment: Apologies I did not think the information relevant given how specific the question was to R#. Having to build just to check if code comments are satisfactory is unfortunately a bit of a hack in this situation. Would be great if there was an R#-based solution that would fit in with the rest of the code standards rules already in place.

Comment: @S.Richmond: See my edit. But I've no idea how much R# warnings will help you - how were you expecting R# to enforce anything? It'll put appropriately coloured bars in the margin, but unless developers check that, I don't think it'll help you much.

Comment: Ah that is fantastic thanks Jon. In regards to your query - 'enforce' may have been too strong a word to use here. I would expect my team to enforce a clean R# analysis themselves rather than some hardlined approach.

Answer (score 2):

Not to compete with Jon but [GhostDoc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) does what you're describing.

[image]

Comment: +1 For a good "best effort" solution but while it can provide a good attempt at auto-documenting, it still doesn't guarantee that changes made by a developer are _good_ changes...

Comment: @Basic Thanks, essentially Check-In Policies are the quality gate on version control, tasks that must be completed before the code can be checked in and built.  Examples are the testing policy to ensure regression bugs are not introduced by a code change, the code analysis policy to ensure checked in code meets certain agreed standards and the Work Item policy to reduce scope creep and help testers to pinpoint what has been included in any given build of the application.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Is GhostDoc much use anymore in VS2012 and above? You can type '///' above any method and it'll auto-generate the commenting standard for you to fill in.

Comment: @S.Richmond GhostDoc also generates text for the tags, not just the tags themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Also, check out [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) which has a Resharper plugin, which means missing comments (for methods, properties, etc) will be shown as Resharper warnings/errors. May, or may not, be of interest for you, but at least it's an option.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options. Both - using extensions for ReSharper - not for Visual Studio (if you didn't know, ReSharper has its own Extension Manager). These extensions are (**use the second one!**):

1. **AgentSmith (for R#9)**. Now, my ReSharper's Extension Manager says, that this extension is for ReSharper of the version 9.0 (which I have installed) but, in fact, this extension works with errors (disabling of highlights works not properly).
2. **XML Doc Inspections for ReSharper 9**. Seems, works without any problems (I have it just installed). *That is what you really need to highlight classes, methods, properties and so on (even private fields) that have no XML comments!*

Answer (score 0):

[Stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) has many rules for comments, you may also want to look at [Stylecop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) as this has some extra rules for Method/Property lengths.